# variable causing unexpected T_VARIABLE error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, iframe

I'm writing some php code in my Wordpress site that works *until* I try to use a variable in the script.  Explanation of operation:

- System is showing an iframe that needs to act as a clickable element
- The iframe takes a couple of seconds to load, causing it to overlay the  tag, so that the iframe isn't clickable.
- The  at the end resets the css and assigns the href attribute after a delay, making the iframe again clickable.
- If I hard-code the URL, all is fine, but if I use a variable, (so that the url can be dynamically assigned), I get an "unexpected '$MYURL' (T_VARIABLE)" error.
- All variables not set in this script segment are set prior, and all works without the $MYURL variable

***The offending line is 348, or near the bottom, and is***

`$(this).attr('href', '<?php echo $MYURL; ?>');`

***This is defined earlier at line 314, which is***

`$MYURL = "http://trailmeister.com/TOPO_VIEWS/showmap.php?gpx={$row[gpx_file]}&trail={$_GET[tname]}";`

**I'm stumped. Before down-voting me, please let me know if you need more information.  The crucial part of this code is in the  section at the end.  Here's the code:**

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $routequery = mysql_query("SELECT * from wp_routes WHERE trail_id = ".$trailid."");
    $MYURL = "http://example.com/showmap.php?gpx=$row[gpx_file]&trail=$_GET[tname]";
    echo "<h2>Rider's Routes</h2><a href='/submit-route?trail=$_GET[trail]'><b>";
    echo "[ Submit a new route ]</b></a><br>";
    if (mysql_num_rows($routequery)){
        require_once('GPXIngest.class.php');    
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($routequery)) {
            $user = get_user_by( 'id', '1' );
            echo "<div style='float:left;margin-right:5px;'>";
            $smallmap = '[iframe  src="http://trailmeister.com/TOPO_VIEWS/showmap2.php';
            $smallmap .= '?gpx='.$row[gpx_file].'&trail='.$_GET[tname].'"]';
            echo "<a id='bigmap' href='http://trailmeister.com/TOPO_VIEWS/showmap.php?";
            echo "gpx=$row[gpx_file]&trail=$_GET[tname]' style='border:1px red solid; ";
            echo "margin-right: -150px; z-index:999; position:absolute; display:inline-block;";
            echo " width:150px; height:150px;'></a>";
            echo do_shortcode($smallmap);
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div><a href='http://trailmeister.com/TOPO_VIEWS/GPX/download.php?";
            echo "gpx=$row[gpx_file]'><b>[ Download this route ]</b></a><br>";
            echo "Submitted $row[submitted] by " .$user->user_nicename."<br>";
            echo "Route Difficulty: $row[difficulty]   |  ";
            echo "Trail Length: $row[trail_length] <br>";
            echo "<i>$row[comments]</i></div>";
            }
        }   
    }
?>
<script>
$('#bigmap')
      .delay(4000)
      .queue( function(next){ 
        $(this).css({
    'border':'1px red solid',
'margin-right': '-150px',
'z-index':'999', 
'position':'absolute',
'display':'inline-block',
'width':'150px',
'height':'150px'
});
$(this).attr('href', '<?php echo $MYURL; ?>');
 
        next();     
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Look at the colour coding. That looks quite wrong.

Comment: What is the line number and exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$MYURL' (T_VARIABLE) in E:\web\public_html\case42\TRAILMEISTER\wp-content\plugins\php-code-for-posts\PHPPostCode.php(85) : eval()'d code on line 348 -

Comment: I assume you don;t want to see ALL 400+ lines of code, when the only difference between working and not is the inclusion of $MYURL. If I'm wrong, please let me know before down-voting me.

Comment: Can you indicate which line the line numbers map to in your 400 lines of code? :)

Comment: Yes.  Line 348 (the offending line) is `$(this).attr('href', '<?php echo $MYURL; ?>');`

Comment: I'd double-check to make sure all of the braces/parens/etc are closed in previous PHP blocks in the file. It may be that some of your previous PHP code left blocks on the stack.

Comment: where using $row['gpx_file'] inside a quoted string, this throws a T_ENCAPSED error. I get the SAME T_VARIABLE error when I concatenate and use quotes in the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this is quite a mess, which is a big part of the problem, I would suggest cleaning it up to begin with and using template syntax for your while loop

```
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($routequery)) {
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', '1' );
        echo "<div style='float:left;margin-right:5px;'>";
        $smallmap = '[iframe  src="http://trailmeister.com/TOPO_VIEWS/showmap2.php';
        $smallmap .= '?gpx='.$row[gpx_file].'&trail='.$_GET[tname].'"]';
        echo "<a id='bigmap' href='http://trailmeister.com/TOPO_VIEWS/showmap.php?";
        echo "gpx=$row[gpx_file]&trail=$_GET[tname]' style
 //...
```

Becomes

```
   <?php
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', '1' ); //why is this in the loop with static values?

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($routequery)):
   ?>

        <div style='float:left;margin-right:5px;'>
        <?php
            $smallmap = '[iframe  src="http://trailmeister.com/TOPO_VIEWS/showmap2.php';
            $smallmap .= '?gpx='.$row["gpx_file"].'&trail='.$_GET["tname"].'"]';
        ?>
        <a id='bigmap' href='http://trailmeister.com/TOPO_VIEWS/showmap.php? "gpx=$row["gpx_file"]&trail=$_GET["tname"]' style
 //...
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Once you do that the problem will be easier to see. Template syntax is like this:

```
  <?php while( $bla ) : ?> 
      html
  <?php endwhile; ?> 

  <?php if( $bla ) : ?> 
      html
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Look into a syntax highlighter even notpad++, AS other have said put quotes around your array keys

```
 $_GET["tname"]
```

Not

```
 =$_GET[tname]
```

PHP will see the later as a undefined constant.  This `may` work in " double quote blocks but it's a bad practice to use.  Use `" text { $_GET['tname'] } text "` instead of `" text $_GET[tname] text "`, it's backwards compatible and not dependent on variable interpolation

Comment: The static value makes this function visible ONLY to the admin for now. I'll try the template syntax.

Comment: This helped me troubleshoot, and I basically re-built the whole thing. I still had to create and refer to variables in my code, and the javascript gave me trouble all the way through. Turned out to be a simple unbalanced quote. Thanks everyone who looked at this.  There's no cure but sleep for tired eyes coding for too many hours at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$smallmap = '[iframe  src="http://trailmeister.com/TOPO_VIEWS/showmap2.php";
```

Notice that you are opening the line with a single quote but closing it with a double quote. Make them consistent -- either both single quotes or both double quotes.

Comment: That was a typo on my part, trying to make the code more readable here, in the narrow viewport - I am consistent in my quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your first $smallmap is not closed (notice how all of the echo's are green after that?)

Comment: was a typo here, not in my code on the server - my browser didn't color-code it for some reason.